# compilation error message: CS1061 with those good answers here i cant fix it

Tags: c#-4.0

'ASP.fletedalja_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'enter_Click' and no extension method 'enter_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.fletedalja_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**please can any one give me an idea?**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace OOP2
{
    public partial class FleteDalja : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void enter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
        }
    }
}




<asp:Button ID="enter" runat="server" onclick="enter_Click" 
                         Text="Enter" />
```